# cakePHP force download of ical

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following in a layout file;

```
<?php
$Filename = "TheEvent.vcs";
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$Filename");
echo $content_for_layout;
?>
```

Now in the controller I have this layout defined and it is working as I can see the text of my ical file. The only problem is the download isn't being forced on the client.

I followed the following guide though I am using cakePHP 2.0

http://labs.iamkoa.net/2007/09/07/create-downloadable-ical-events-via-cake/

Thanks

Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the new 2.0 request features to download right away:

```
$this->response->download($filename);
```

http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/11/21/serving-views-as-files-in-cake2/

You can use file() and the other documented ways of serving files - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse

Comment: Not sure why, but it showed me `Method download does not exist` while `$this->response->download($filename);` worked [just fine](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-CakeResponse.html). Note `request` replaced with `response`.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica You were right, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **"Content-Type: application/force-download"** is used and not recognized by your HTTPd server.
Thus your php script is an unknown type of content and your browser got the signal to download the file and save it :)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer got me `Method download does not exist`.

Here's what worked for me:

```
$this->response->download($filename);
```

Note `request` replaced with `response`.

Source: [class-CakeResponse.html](http://api.cakephp.org/2.0/class-CakeResponse.html).